# form_for routing problem with nested resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Seeing a problem with using form_for with a nested resource where I have remapped the route to be more sensible.

My routes.rb:

```
resources :books do
  resources :sections, :controller => 'content_sections'
  member do
    post 'publish'
  end
end
```

And my _form.html.haml

```
= form_for [@book, @content_section] do |f|
  -if @content_section.errors.any?
    #error_explanation
      %h2= "#{pluralize(@content_section.errors.count, "error")} prohibited this section from being saved:"
      %ul
        - @content_section.errors.full_messages.each do |msg|
          %li= msg

  .field
    = f.label :name
    = f.text_field :name
```

This is resulting in this error:

```
undefined method `book_content_sections_path' for #<#<Class:0x00000103a58238>:0x00000103a4a0e8>
```

What I'm expecting is `book_sections_path` but it is failing to take into account the setting in routes.rb.

Comment: please add rake routes output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since there is no real relationship between models and controllers, then you will need to specify the URL when not using standard conventions:

```
form_for [@book, @content_section], :url => book_sections_path(@book, @content_section)
```

Comment: Thanks, sorry I'm a bit new and I find the documentation overly focused on the conventions, which are great for about 5 minutes at which point you move on to the real world.  What is weird is I swear I had this working and then when I renamed BookSection to ContentSection (model, controller an related views were renamed) it stopped.  You would think it could adjust to the routes settings.

Comment: Actually the many problem with this is that there are two paths depending on whether or not you are creating or editing: